# teleconverter for a Canon Powershot SX50 HS

Tags: canon, teleconverter, bird-photography

I have a Canon Powershot SX50 HS camera and use it a lot for bird photography ( goes up to 200mm).
Is it worth getting a X2 teleconverter lens or will the loss in image quality offset the magnification gained?

With small birds I don't always get the resolution I woul d like.

Comment: Do you mean it goes up to 1200mm?  That is the spec I see.  The converter will leave you at f/13 at the long end, where you will probably have a lot of diffraction if nothing else.  You may have difficulty with the autofocus as well.

Comment: It is also not clear how the image stabilization will cope with that.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the 2x teleconverter you are considering?

Comment: The only teleconverter I could find fo rthis camera was one manufacted by Gloxy at £44. It is SKU: VDTS-3774   MPN: TP58  EAN: 8436537140063.The URL is https://www.photo24.co.uk/telephoto-lens-for-canon-powershot-sx50-hs

Answer (score 1):

With the SX50's crop factor you are already at 1200mm equivalent... even if the 2x diopter thing was of top quality (and it's not), 2400mm effective is near useless. Even with great technique/stability/IS environmental conditions will almost always degrade IQ at the distances where that kind of FL might have use.

I would say forget the adaptor and work on fieldcraft/getting closer.

Comment: Thnaks for the advice. I gather a crop factor is the same as the focal length multiplier. Are you saying the 200 mm length then multiplied by this factor 7.70 gives an effective telephoto lens  of 1200mm?

Comment: @ Bruce, yes... the specs for the SX50's zoom lens is "24-1200mm (35mm equivalent)." Whether that is truly equivalent to lenses with longer focal lengths depends on whether the lens or the sensor has the greater resolution.